# 550 5.7.1 relaying denied

Tags: php, sendmail, telnet, centos6

I wonder if can send email from server A using ip address of server B
I tried to send email from my application using bellow code but it returns "550 5.7.1 relaying denied".

```
function    sendmail($p_subject,$p_message)
{
    $ip         = 'ipServerB';
    $domain     = 'domain';
    $returnPath = 'contact@domain';     
    $to         = 'to';
    $subject    = 'New Ticket : '.$subject;
    $message    = $message;
    $header     = "from:support@domain\nto:$to\nsubject:$subject\n$message\n.\n";

    $fp = fsockopen($ip, 25);


    $telnet    = array();
    $telnet[0] = "telnet $ip\r\n";
    $telnet[1] = "HELO $domain\r\n";
    $telnet[2] = "MAIL FROM:$returnPath\r\n";
    $telnet[3] = "RCPT TO:$to\r\n";
    $telnet[4] = "DATA\r\n";
    $telnet[5] = $header;


    foreach ($telnet as $current) 
    {         
                fwrite($fp, $current);
                $smtpOutput=fgets($fp);
                echo $smtpOutput.'               ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't roll your own mailer**. Use a class such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Sending emails manually will, more often than not, result in "unclean" mail data with a very high risk of being considered spam, and/or problems in dealing with errors and retries.

In this case for example you're sending nonsensical data such as a `telnet` command (which should get you `502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized`), the SMTP conversation is totally blind, and the session is truncated rather than closed correctly. If you ever succeed in sending an email this way, it will be mostly due to sheer luck, and you shouldn't expect to be able to repeat the feat with any reliability.

That said, "relaying denied" means that neither the address you're sending the mail *from*, nor the address you're sending the mail *to*, are under the control of the server you're using. Therefore, the server would need to "relay" the email to someone else; and since you're not an authorized user, it refuses to do so.

Try using SMTP AUTH commands to send the server a valid set of credentials.

For comparison, this is how you would do it with PHPMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = $AddressB;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $UserNameOnServerB;
$mail->Password = $PasswordOnServerB;

$mail->From     = 'yourfrom@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Ticket System';
$mail->AddAddress('joe@example.com', 'Joe Bloggs');
$mail->AddAddress('bob@example.com', 'Bob Smith');

$mail->IsHTML(true);                         

$mail->Subject = 'Ticket no. ....';
$mail->Body    = '<h1>It works!</h1><hr /><p>This is the email</p>';
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($mail->Body);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
   die('Boo hoo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
echo 'OK!';
```

Comment: thanks for your awesome  answer ! could you tell me please which Username and paswword should I use in this case ?

Comment: Username and password must be given to you by the SMTP server administrator; you can't log in unless you have the right. In some cases, the SMTP server of your ISP will accept connection from an IP of its own without authentication (i.e.: if you have a DSL subscription with FooBar DSL, you can connect to smtp.foobar.baz without further authentication). But you need to ask all this to your provider.